# Aptana Studio 3 MAC OS freezes intermittently when scrolling through JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, macos, aptana

Am writing a page with lots of javascript, in multiple files.

Intermittently, Aptana will decide that some point in a particular file is no-man's-land: whenever I try to scroll that section onscreen, Aptana hangs - I can no longer scroll up/down, switch tabs, type, etc. However it DOES allow me to CMD-Q and kill it.

I like Aptana in general, but this has started cropping up more frequently lately, and it's becoming a blocker.

I'm not even sure how to begin debugging this one, as I can't reproduce it consistently.

I usually have 8-12 files open, and it works most of the time, until a bit gets flipped somehow in one of the files, and then that file becomes 'broken' - I can't view the whole thing. Usually the 'bad bit' is somewhere nearer the end, so I can scroll around above that point - but if I try to put the 'bad bit' onscreen, it hangs.

This is Mac OS, Snow Leopard, doing JS development, new MBP.

I can still access the menus, and have tried Close, Close All, etc. The menus respond, but the main UI area does not.

My previous workaround is to open the file in vi, make a change, save it, and re-open Aptana. My theory was that a CR/LF character switched charsets or something, and that re-saving it might help smooth things over. That is no longer fixing it, so it seems to be getting worse.

Also tried closing all files in the workspace and shutting down, then reopening only that one, no luck.

Thanks for any thoughts!

A

Final update for anyone else who stumbles onto this:
To fix, go to Preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Editors -> Javascript, and make sure "Initially fold these elements: Comments" is turned OFF. That was causing the problem for me. (Probably a good idea to disable initial folding on everything, and might apply to more languages than JS.)

(Sorry for the "solved", Harpo - still a SON00b. Thought it was the courteous thing to do.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible you might be encountering this issue: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3992. If so, there is a fix in that should be available in the next beta.

Comment: Winner! In a mere 6 minutes, you pointed me to the issue that has been tripping me up for 3 days. BLESS YOU, SIR! ;)

Comment: That beta is now available (see http://preview.appcelerator.com/studio/, click on Aptana Studio tab, and choose RC or beta streams)